# unexplained Compilation error

Tags: java-ee-5

In a project, the developer used `HttpServletResponse.setContentTYpe()`, followed by `HttpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding()`; There was a compilation error at the deployment setup due to `response.setCharacterEncoding`.

It was quite apparent that the `HttpServletResponse` class was missing, yet to double check I did lots of research and figured out that the most plausible reason could be that `servlet-api.jar` and `jsp-api.jar` are not getting included in the `classpath` during build process. I got it checked at developer end also, yet the error was still there. So I asked on of the guys who is a veteran in the process, and the cause that he put up was that the error was due to `HttpServletResponse.setContentTYpe()`, followed by `HttpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding()`, and after replacing the two lines with `HttpServletResponse.setContentType("application/json;UTF8")` its working fine.

I again went through the javadocs to see if it's possible, but I didnt got any such logic. Can anyone tell me if its possible that these two methods can cause compilation error.
Or do I need to start learning Java from Complete Reference.

Comment: Wow!... still no answer. Experts please help me out.